# Showing that for $s,t\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have $(s+t)^*= s^* + t^*$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm working through the problems of Elementary Analysis Theory of Calculus, and for some reason, this question didn't make the solutions in the back of the book. I did a thorough search on Stack Exchange and could not find a similar problem.  I was wondering if anyone could help me verify my proof.  Some background:

$$s,t \in \Bbb Q, \quad s^∗ = \{r \in \Bbb Q : r < s\}$$ is a Dedekind cut where $s$ is in $\Bbb Q$.  So, it is a rational Dedekind cut.

$t^*$ is defined similarly.

$$(s+t)^* = \{r ∈ \Bbb Q : r < s + t\}$$

$$s^* + t^* = \{r1 + r2 : r_1 \in s^* \text{ and} r_2 ∈ t^*\}$$

So, to show that $s^* + t^*$ is a subset of $(s+t)^*$ is quite easy.  To show $(s+t)^* \subseteq s^* + t^*$ was quite difficult for me.  But, I think I have it now.  Here goes.

Suppose $x ∈ (s+t)^*$.  Then, $x ∈ \Bbb Q$ and $x < s + t$.  By the density of $\Bbb Q$, there is an $m$ in $\Bbb Q$ such that $x < m < s + t$.  Let $\varepsilon = m - x$.  So, $x < x + \varepsilon < s + t$.  So, $x + \varepsilon - s < t$.

Define $x$ as follows:

$$x = (s-ϵ) + (t - (t - x + (s-\varepsilon))). $$

Clearly, $s-\varepsilon < s$.  Since $s-\varepsilon ∈ \Bbb Q, s-\varepsilon ∈ s^*$ .  Likewise,

$$(t - (t - x + (s-\varepsilon))) = x - s + \varepsilon < t.$$  Since $(t - (t - x + (s-\varepsilon))) ∈ \Bbb Q$ and $(t - (t - x + (s-\varepsilon))) < t, (t - (t - x + (s-\varepsilon))) ∈ t^*$.

Hence, $x = r_1 + r_2$ such that $r_1 ∈ s^*$ and $r_2 ∈ t^*$.  Thus, $x ∈ s^* + t^*$ and $(s+t)^* \subseteq s^* + t^*$

Is this proof valid?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct.

A minor quibble: when you say "Define $x$ as follows", you are not actually defining $x$. That was already defined when you said "Suppose $x\in (s+t)^*$. You are actually *rewriting* $x$ in a different form — if you unpack all the parentheses then the RHS of that expression is just $x$ written in a convoluted way.

[But of course you took advantage of that form to solve the problem, which was the point. It could be done without the $t$'s, but it's fine as is.]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I also realized that x was overly rewritten.  The t's do not need to be in there, and the proof works fine.  So, x=(s−ϵ)+(t−(t−x+(s−ε))) should just be x=(s−ϵ)+ (x-(s−ε)).